# How to open the default browser and make it do a POST request in C#?

Tags: c#, post, browser

I think this is impossible, but I'd love to be proven wrong:

From my C# app, if the user clicks a button, I open the system's default browser with a certain URL like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.some-website.com");
```

Now, on that website there is a button that performs a POST request and updates the content of the site, without changing the URL. I would like to directly show that updated site, rather than having the user clicking around on the website manually.

**Is there any way to do this programmatically in C#?**

One idea is doing the POST in C# and somehow pass the response to the browser.
I know how to do HTTP requests in C# and I know what parameters I need to send here, but I don't know of a way to make the browser display the response.

Any other ideas are welcome, too.

Comment: What kind of application is this? Can you host a WebBrowser control instead of starting the default browser? Otherwise, see something like [Selenium C Sharp](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-c-sharp/)

Comment: @Jimi simple forms app. So yes, WebBrowser control is possible, but not desired. Will have a look at your link. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add some details on the reason why the WebBrowser control is not *desired*. Note that, when correctly configured, it behaves as IE11 in Windows 7 and Edge in Windows 10.

Comment: @Jimi well, short answer is because customer doesn't like IE. But if this is the only way, I will try to convince them

Comment: Ah, well, if the customer doesn't like it... :) Anyway, Selenium is quite good (and really simple, if you just need to click buttons). Go to [Selenium HQ](https://www.seleniumhq.org/) for a tour.